# DHCP server management API in dot net application

Tags: .net, winapi, c#-4.0, dhcp

I need to use DHCP server management API in my C#.net application. My target platform is  Windows Server 2008 R2 (64 bit obvious I guess). I am getting this error 
"A reference to 'dhcpsapi.dll' could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component."

Assuming it is a COM dll I even tried TLB export but with error 
TlbExp : error TX0000 : Could not load file or assembly 'dhcpsapi.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

I found this assembly in C:\Windows\System32 folder. I have also tried starting VS in "Run as Admin" mode. Any help, highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dhcpsapi.dll isn't a COM dll.  It's a plain DLL, and you'll need to use P/Invoke to call functions in it.  [PInvoke.Net](http://pinvoke.net/) is a good place to look for prewritten P/Invoke calls.

Comment: Thanks Eric for the direction. I am up voting this. I'll definitely come back and mark it as answer after trying this out.

Comment: I found a managed wrapper for my purpose in [Code.MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/ManageDHCP-Manage-your-6bb4f69f). Hope this helps someone looking for dhcp management from managed code.